# How to use the extension methods for HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm struggling with something that should be pretty basic for the professionals.
I'm trying to use an extension wrapper for httpWebRequest. the extension class looks like this:

```
    public static class WebRequestExtensions
{
    public static Stream GetRequestStreamWithTimeout(
        this WebRequest request,
        int? millisecondsTimeout = null)
    {
        return AsyncToSyncWithTimeout(
            request.BeginGetRequestStream,
            request.EndGetRequestStream,
            millisecondsTimeout ?? request.Timeout);
    }

    public static WebResponse GetResponseWithTimeout(
        this HttpWebRequest request,
        int? millisecondsTimeout = null)
    {
        return AsyncToSyncWithTimeout(
            request.BeginGetResponse,
            request.EndGetResponse,
            millisecondsTimeout ?? request.Timeout);
    }

    private static T AsyncToSyncWithTimeout<T>(
        Func<AsyncCallback, object, IAsyncResult> begin,
        Func<IAsyncResult, T> end,
        int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        var iar = begin(null, null);
        if (!iar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout))
        {
            var ex = new TimeoutException();
            throw new WebException(ex.Message, ex, WebExceptionStatus.Timeout, null);
        }
        return end(iar);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the wrapper methods `GetResponseWithTimeout` and `GetRequestStreamWithTimeout` but I don't know how to do this. The working code should look like this:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
requestStream = request.GetRequestStreamWithTimeout();
```

How can I achieve this?

**Edit**

I've tried to derive the main class from the extension class which let's me use the wrapper methods but now I'm getting this error message:

Error   3   'chunkedUpload.UploadFile': cannot derive from static class 'chunkedUpload.WebRequestExtensions'

Comment: Did you include the namespace of your WebRequestExtensions class into the file of your calling code ? `using ...;` (By the way, did you mean you cannot build your code ?)

Comment: Yes I just did. I read the article here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042(v=vs.100).aspx which explains how custom method can be implemented. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: OK :-) So what is your exact problem ? What is the (build ?) error you got ?

Comment: Ohh my problem is solved now. I didn't know how to use extension class. I read a couple of articles and found out how to. My code compiles fine and the code works :) Can you help me with another small issue?